# Failed to invoke chaincode name:"scbcch" , error: timeout expired while executing transaction

Tags: indexing, couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I am trying to fetch data from blockchain using query in chaincode. I have invoked around 2,50,000 records in blockchain and trying to fetch the data using query. When i run the chaincode and get the peer logs, I am getting the below error.

```
failed to invoke chaincode name:"scbcch" , error: timeout expired while executing transaction
```

When i do a query for lesser data my code works fine without these errors.

Can anybody please help me in solving the issue please.

I am using **Hyperledger Fabric 1.4**.

Here is my Query code:

```
queryString := fmt.Sprintf("{\"selector\":{\"_id\": {\"$gt\": null},\"$and\":[{\"terminationReportID\":{\"$ne\":\"%s\"}},{\"terminationReportFlag\":{\"$eq\":\"%s\"}},{\"effectiveDateOfAction\":{\"$gt\":\"%s\"}},{\"importDate\":{\"$eq\":\"%s\"}}]},\"fields\": [\"bankID\",\"effectiveDateOfAction\",\"costCentre\"],\"use_index\":[\"_design/indexTerminationReportDoc\",\"indexTerminationReportName\"]}","null", "Yes", "2018-10-31", lastImportDatekey)

queryResultss11, errtr := getQueryResultForQueryString(stub, queryString)
```

And my Indexing is:

```
{"index":{"fields":["terminationReportID","terminationReportFlag","effectiveDateOfAction","importDate"]},"ddoc":"indexTerminationReportDoc", "name":"indexTerminationReportName","type":"json"}
```

Can anyone please help me to figure out and resolve the issue. I am stuck with this for more than 3 days.

Is there anything I have to change on my index part. I am re-posting the same issue as I am not getting any support for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the chaincode execution timeout.You can customize it in the docker file of your peers.

```
CORE_CHAINCODE_EXECUTETIMEOUT=80s
```

Comment: Thank you @shubham for the reponse. I have already added this line in my docker compose.yml. But Is it correct if I add it in peer configuration?